# Does Windows 2008 Server Standard Edition, support Network Load Balancing?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, load-balancing, nlb

Does Windows 2008 Server Standard Edition, support Network Load Balancing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Windows 2008 Standard supports NLB. [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-differentiated-features.aspx) is a chart from Microsoft showing many different features. It is for R2, but applies to "R1" as well.