# Windows 2008 Server Standard Edition, supports Component Load Balancing?

Tags: windows, networking, load-balancing

Windows 2008 Server Standard Edition, supports Component Load Balancing? if not, what SO do I need?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/138373/windows-2008-server-standard-edition-supports-nlb

Comment: Not a duplicate, component/COM+ load balancing is a different feature than NLB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this Microsoft forum post (from a Microsoft employee) it looks like COM+/component load balancing will not be available in Windows 2008.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverMigration/thread/97969ae7-6473-40e8-9f0a-305ed1baf7f9

Answer (score 0):

No, no sql server supports that ;) YOu miss a multi master backend for that to make sense. It only works in read only mode for the databases.